# Separating client and server side deployments JavaEE & Website dev

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I need to deploy 2 packages to `Wildfly`:
1. EAR file - containing all server side (`JavaEE`) code.
2. WAR file - containing website code (HTML,JS,CSS...).

In order for the website path to be something like `localhost:8080/somename/index.html`, I need to specify `<finalName>somename</finalName>` in Maven. On the other hand, the EAR file contains the RESTful stuff, and in order for the REST to be under the `somename` context root I added  the appropriate tag to `maven-ear-plugin`.
Now... I guess Wildfly doesn't like 2 things to be registered under same name, so I can't deploy the website.

What is the proper way to approach this problem? Combine the two projects under the same name and deliver only one package?? maybe change the context root of the EAR since it's "the RESTful voodoo stuff" that is not really important?

I would really want to register the two under the same context root but leave both projects separated.

Comment: Why not simply use a multi-module Maven project with a single WAR deployment? You can put all your EJB and REST stuff into separate Maven modules but still build a single WAR where the EJB and REST modules end up in WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Everything has its own module. All server side code is packaged in a single ear file containing an ejb file and a war file (for REST). The website is packaged separately in another war in order to replace it if I need to,  not doing anything to the server code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't register two different WAR's under the same context. Since you want to leave the business logic separate from the UI it's probably best to register the WAR with your REST services under a different context.